# Dúvida com chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, sql, relacionamento, chave-estrangeira, chave-primária

Para registrar os jogos de um campeonato de futebol foram definidas as seguintes tabelas:

```
Time (
    id int primary key,
    nome char(20),
    pontos int, 
    nroVitorias, 
    golsMarcados int, 
    golsSofridos int )

Jogo (
    idTime1 int, 
    idTime2 int, 
    golsTime1 int, 
    golsTime2, 
    primary key (idTime1, idTime2) )
```

A tabela **Time** está previamente carregada com os dados `id` e `nome` de todos os times que participam do campeonato e com todos os
demais valores zerados. A tabela **Jogos** está vazia.
Escreva os comandos SQL para resolver as seguintes requisições:

As colunas `idTime1` e `idTme2` devem ser definidas como chaves estrangeiras referenciando a tabela **Time**.

Escreva os comandos para definição dessas 2 chaves estrangeiras de modo que um time que já tenha algum jogo cadastrado não pode ser excluído e se o id de um time for alterado, os seus jogos são preservados.

É possível eu criar uma chave estrangeira à partir de uma coluna em uma tabela (Time), referenciando duas colunas em outra tabela (Jogos)?

Obrigado.

Comment: pode sim. se você estiver utilizando o phpmyadmim, o proprio faz isso muito facilmente.

Comment: Adicione o que você já tentou para o exercício.

Comment: @8biT ALTER TABLE Time ADD CONSTRAINT TimeJogo FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Jogo (idTime1, idTime2);

Comment: Certo, o que exatamente você quer dizer com `e se o id de um time for alterado, os seus jogos são preservados.` ? Em algum momento será alterado o ID (Primary Key) do Time ? Como será feito isso ?

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi direito você deseja saber como e se é possível relacionar duas colunas de uma tabela com uma outra coluna de outra tabela, não permitindo a exclusão de registros que já estejam populadas entre estas "relações".

Na sua tentativa você está declarando `foreign key` em uma mesma instrução. Porém você deve declarar as suas novas `foreign key`    da seguinte maneira:

**Exemplo:**

```
ALTER TABLE Luta
    ADD CONSTRAINT id_fk_fighter1 FOREIGN KEY (lutador1) REFERENCES lutador (id),
    ADD CONSTRAINT id_fk_fighter2 FOREIGN KEY (lutador2) REFERENCES lutador (id);
```

- Com isso a "luta" que no seu caso é o `Jogo` terá referencias ao lutador 1 e lutador 2.
- Todos "lutadores" que possuírem uma luta marcada não poderão ser excluídos.